# TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined | Schema issue?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I get the cannot read property 'split' of undefined when I do the following code:

```
router.get("/startup/:id", function(req, res) {
    // This uses the id in the url to find the id in the 
    // database then passes the data into foundStartup
    Startup.findById(req.params.id).exec(function(err, foundStartup){
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            var split = foundStartup.aboutstartup.techstack.split(",");
            res.render("startup/show", {startup :foundStartup, split: split});
        }
    });
});
```

It used to work then I went and removed all the '_' from the schema and therefore everywhere I had the schema called. I have no idea why this error would pop up now. I have gone through every file I created for this project and nothing is left with the old references. I have also spent 2 ish hours on google and stackoverflow looking at others solutions and none have worked for me so I am back to the code I started with that used to work.

Suggestions on solutions? Maybe I should add error checking now instead of later?

Comment: do you understand that the error is telling you that `foundStartup.aboutstartup.techstack` is undefined ... so `foundStartup.aboutstartup` is fine, but it has no `techstack` property

Comment: I get it is saying that but when I put a console.log above it, it prints out the string it is supposed to

Comment: so the error isn't being generated on the line `var split = foundStartup.aboutstartup.techstack.split(",");` if `foundStartup.aboutstartup.techstack` is a string - the error message should include a line the error is generated on